# Datasets with different information - single table or 1 per set?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm in a group with other classmates designing software that will allow a user to upload historical data about an area, and then filter that data based on other column information. The column information can be completely different per set of data. For example, we have a large CSV containing information about people living in Philadelphia from the late 1700's, including columns like:

> Occupation, Widow, African, Address, Comments

**Addresses are the only common attribute across sets.**

I thought we should create a new table for each dataset, since we can't know what future columns will be or how many there will be. Someone can upload a file tomorrow will information about chicken farmers, and columns like

> Had chickens with brown eggs, Wheat, Address, Apples

I only know what I've taught myself, but I've since been told by other classmates that new tables per set is ***dirty*** in a philosophical sense. The only competing design is a single table with multiple generic "attribute" columns, which is kept separated-by-set with meta information/another table describing the attributes.

I'm having difficulty seeing the downsides with making a new table for each set, but I'm not confident enough in my street-education of MySQL to drive a strong case for it-- ***particularly*** if there's a better way to be doing it. I've only been told that it's anti-database (not in those terms though -- my teammates are awesome and I just want to understand.)

It seems like using a separate table would let us pick a specific datatype (`varchar`, `datetime`, etc) and keep the queries restricted to relevant data before even running the actual statement. **Plus**, the alternative solution would need new generic columns if we get a dataset with many columns, even if the previous/future sets never need it again. I understand (in part) their reasoning for it and think it would work -- but I'm having trouble seeing the benefit for seemingly more work.

Is there a "correct" way of doing this?

Edit:
The filtering is ultimately used to plot the points on a map using Google's Maps API. Code for geocoding the addresses is already done for the most part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you going to query those fields that are different from dataset to dataset or just display the information? If it is just for display, you could put all that information in one field. If you need to query it this is a bad idea. You could also use an EAV table in which case, I might wonder if a relational database is the best choice for this information (other than the addres stuff). I would investigate a no sql database for this. 
Or you could do a table for each kind of information and join to them.  In this case though, I'm not sure it would be effective becasue you would have so many of them and not know which one sto join to for any one query.

Comment: I was just going to suggest to put all the information in one field too :)

Comment: Actually, someone had suggested investigating the NoSQL thing as well! I'm definitely interested and will take a look. It seems like both you and @webdevbyjoss mentioned EAV, so I'll get on reading about that right away. The idea is that I could choose an attribute column from a drop-down and ask for a value; I could select all African Doctors from the Phila dataset and see the addresses.

Comment: noSQl can often handle EAV type data better than a relational database, so I would look at it. I believe thsi is exactly the kind of thing that noSQL databases were designed to handle.

Comment: Thanks for the extra help! I wish I had enough rep to upvote! :)

Answer (score 0):

if you're just going to filter it (and I don't think you'll be able to do much more than that), put everything in one table, and add an extra column (a foreign key) that points to another table that has the name of the set (in case the user want's all the data in a set.

I suggest to put everything in one table, because it sounds, feels and looks like you're trying to build some kind of data warehouse with data from different sources, which are not consistent between themselves.

You might want to create defaults for the columns that are not populated, but that strongly depends on how you're going to use the data.

Comment: Ah, I'll add an edit to the main post: Ultimately, the filtering is used for plotting points with Google's Maps API. That part (geocoding the addresses) has largely been coded. As far as I know, data will only be accessed from the same set at a time. Cross-set queries aren't intended, which is why I originally thought separate tables. With this information, does it still make sense to stick it in the same table? Each set is consistent with itself, just not with future or pre-existing sets. Sorry if my original post was unclear at all, I'll try to clarify. Thank you for the quick answer!

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to use an EAV (entity-attribute-value) approach. There is a lot of information on how to implement that for MySQL.

Anyway if you will have to search/filter that data you can build a search index for it or a separate search-table for each data set that has a similar set of attributes.

For example you can have the following tables: products,
attributes,
values.

and to allow quick and effective search we can create and periodically re-build a special search index or separate search tables with common attributes for particular set of products like:

search_tools,
search_furniture,
search_otheritems

Comment: Thanks! Both you and @HLGEM mentioned an EAV approach, so I'll definitely start reading up on it. I appreciate the help; like I said, I only know what I've taught myself and wouldn't of had this insight otherwise!